# mockito - mock protected method in different packages

Tags: mockito, powermockito

I am writing the test case using mockito for a protected method.

```
public HttpResponse createPostRequest(HashMap<String, String> requestHeaders, String url, String methodName)
    {
        //some logic
    }
```

my class is in src/main/java and test case is in different package src/main/test.
and am using the following.

```
Mockito.doReturn(mockHttpResponse).when(userServiceImpl).createPostRequest(Mockito.any(HashMap.class),
                Mockito.any(String.class),Mockito.any(String.class));
```

but it is not working. It is asking to change the method signature to public.
Please help on that.

Thanks.

Comment: Usage of reflection API can be an option

Comment: @GarimaGupta * If you want to make the code look ugly.

Answer (score 0):

This seems a configuration problem with your project structure. Your main class is in `src/main/java` and test class is in `src/main/test` with one source folder `src`.

While you could get this to work (setting source folders in buildpath etc.), but most of the time below project structure is used (eg. in [*spring boot/ maven*](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)):

- Project-Name

  - bin
  - lib
  - src

    - main

      - java

        - SomeMainClass.java
      - resources
    - test

      - java

        - TestSomeMainClass.java
      - resources

This structure has two source folders, one for main (`src/main/java`) and other one for test (`src/test/java`). This has the advantage that `TestSomeMainClass` can access the `package private` i.e. `default` member fields of `SomeMainClass`.

Comment: yes the project sstructure is src/main/java and src/test/java. but with default modifier am not able to mock the method. It is asking to modify the modifier as public

Answer (score 0):

The project structure is src/main/java and src/test/java. but with default modifier not able to mock the method. It is asking to modify the modifier as public